# Completing an implementation: Container for dependency injection with interfaces

Tags: delphi, dependency-injection, interface, containers

I'm looking to complete this implementation.

It is a very simple model of a container for dependency injection with interfaces in Delphi.

I was watching a class on YouTube, where the methods are presented, but only their signature and nothing about how the implementation was done.

I managed to write almost all of them, I think they will work, with the exception of one of the main functions: "function Get<I: IInterface>: I;"

```
unit uContainerDefault;

interface

uses
  System.TypInfo,
  System.SysUtils,
  System.Generics.Collections;

type
  TGetter = TFunc<IInterface>;

  TContainer = class
  strict private
    FRecords: TDictionary<PTypeInfo, TGetter>;

    class var FDefault: TContainer;
    class function GetDefault: TContainer; static;

  public
    class constructor Create;
    class destructor Destroy;

    constructor Create;
    destructor Destroy; override;

    procedure Register<I: IInterface>(const pGetter: TGetter);

    function Get<I: IInterface>: I;

    class property Default: TContainer read GetDefault;
  end;

implementation

{ TContainer }

class constructor TContainer.Create;
begin
  FDefault := TContainer.Create;
end;

constructor TContainer.Create;
begin
  FRecords := TDictionary<PTypeInfo, TGetter>.Create;
end;

destructor TContainer.Destroy;
begin
  FRecords.Free;
  inherited;
end;

class destructor TContainer.Destroy;
begin
  FDefault.Free;
end;

function TContainer.Get<I>: I;
begin
  {With this code, can I get from the dictionary what "TFunc<IInterface>" is that will result in the interface,
  but I don't know if I should use it to form the result.}
  FRecords.Items[TypeInfo(I)];
end;

class function TContainer.GetDefault: TContainer;
begin
  Result := FDefault;
end;

procedure TContainer.Register<I>(const pGetter: TGetter);
begin
  FRecords.Add(TypeInfo(I), pGetter);
end;

end.
```

Example of how the Register method is called when initializing a class "TProduct":

```
initialization
  TContainer.Default.Register<IProduct>(
    function: IInterface
    begin
      Result := TProduct.Create;
    end);
```

Example of how the Get method is called on a form that will work with the "Product" entity:

```
begin
  TContainer.Default.Get<IProduct>.GetProduct;
end;
```

```
function TContainer.Get<I>: I;
begin
  {With this code, can I get from the dictionary what "TFunc<IInterface>" is that will result in the interface,
  but I don't know if I should use it to form the result.}
  FRecords.Items[TypeInfo(I)];
end;
```

Comment: What video, please?

Comment: @DelphiCoder https://youtu.be/NmNLdNVo0d8?t=1836 
This is the friendly video, unfortunately it is in Portuguese, but it is quite interesting.

Answer (score 2):

after trying a little harder, I did it!
It's working very well.

See how it turned out:

```
function TContainer.Get<I>: I;
begin
  Supports(FRecords.Items[TypeInfo(I)], PTypeInfo(TypeInfo(I)).TypeData.GUID, Result);
end;
```

Would anyone like to add something?
Thanks

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).